# File upload problems

Tags: php, html

i want to upload video,audio, images, pdf, ppt, word files and then save them into a directory...here is my code for uploading,.,,, there is no error but no output as well... when i open the folder thres no image file in it... plus it would be very helpful if u guys tell me how should i upload pdf,word and video files as well...

Heres what I have so far:

this is    add-material.php

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="add-material-action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Upload Your File Here:</label><input type="file" name="uploadedfile" id="uploadedfile"/><br /><br />

<input class="mybutton" type="submit" name="Add Material" class="button"  value="Add  Material" />
```

as my form is pretty big so im pasting pnly the relevant lines of code here

this is    add-material-action.php

```
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]));
if (( ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
 if ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["error"] > 0)
 {
 echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["error"] . "<br />";
 }

 elseif (file_exists("learningmaterial/" . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"],
  "learningmaterial/" . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "learningmaterial/" . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];
  }
}
else
{
 echo "Invalid file";
}
```

thanx in advance :)

Comment: Do you understand the code you wrote? If you did, you would see the explicit checks for the MIME types and extensions for your files... and you could do the same for other types of files...

Comment: "irrelevant lines of code" might actually be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should at the very least get a "Invalid File error." So it's interesting that you're not getting any output after processing.

I would recommend the following:

Similar to $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png"), I would do the same for the mime-types and do an in_array(type, collection)

This makes it easy to add additional extensions and mime-types to the whitelist.

I would also print specific error messages to be more useful

```
if (!in_array($mime, $mimeCollection)) {
   echo "Invalid mime-type";
} else if (!in_array($ext, $extCollection)) {
   echo "Invalid file extension";
} else if ($size > $max) {
   echo "File is too large";
} 

... additional checks
```

I would also enable error reporting to see if something else is going on since you're not getting any output.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

I prefer to check my logs, however, vs enabling reporting in my scripts.

Comment: still no improvement...there is no error at all...i've placed aal the checks and all the MIME types correctly...

Comment: I was able to upload a file to my server using your code. The only thing I was warned about initially was the directory to move the file to did not exists. After creating the directory, it worked fine and I verified the file. If you haven't done so already, verify that the destination directory is actually there.

Answer (score 1):

You have taken
`$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");`

But you want to upload video,audio, images, pdf, ppt, word.
So first of all edit your extension list as follows

`$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png","txt","doc","pdf","mp3");`

add all extensions you want to upload code seems to be perfectly fine, please check if you have permissions in required folder for uploading

Comment: yes i have the permissions to upload.. what could be the problem ??? im just a beginner and couldnot find out the problem.. :(

Comment: when i debug my code it gives a warning on this line..

     if(!move_uploaded_file(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"])){ echo "can't move file"; }

and the warning is   only variables should be passed by reference

i would be thankful to you for any kind of help

Comment: function move_uploaded_file requires sourcepath and destination path..but in your code if(!move_uploaded_file(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"])) no destination path is specifeid..i think this is causing error since syntax is not proper so its causing code to terminate execution

Answer (score 0):

try this you need a return true for success

```
if(!move_uploaded_file(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"],
  "learningmaterial/" . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]))
    {
        echo "can't move file";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using WinSCP.
All I had to do is refresh the server-side so that I could see the new uploads.
[image]